# Android- SetOutlineAmbientShadowColor No such method error on api < 28

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a custom button renderer that extends MaterialButtonRenderer.

I need to use:

```
Control.SetOutlineAmbientShadowColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
Control.SetOutlineSpotShadowColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
```

but this works only with API >= 28.

There is a workaround to make it works with lower API?
I need to run the application from **API 26**.

[image]

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the button style in the styles.xml

```
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton</item>
```

Here is a screenshot about it running result in android 7.0.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It's possible to apply this style to some buttons only?