# Xamarin.Forms.android:Button.UseDefaultShadow not applying properly on RadButton (gets overridden?)

Tags: android, xamarin, button, telerik-radbutton

I have this problem with telerik RadButton, im trying to use the platform specific UseDefaultShadow of android, which works fine on a regular Button but not a RadButton.

The way im doing it is by setting a global style in App.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:telerikInput="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.Input;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.Input"
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             x:Class="App3.App">
    <Application.Resources>

                <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="telerikInput:RadButton">             
              <Setter Property="android:Button.UseDefaultPadding" Value="false" />
              <Setter Property="android:Button.UseDefaultShadow " Value="true" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Quicksand-Regular.otf#Quicksand" />
                <Setter Property="MinimumHeightRequest" Value="50" />
                <Setter Property="MinimumWidthRequest" Value="50" />

                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="DarkTurquoise"/>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="60" />


            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="Button">         
              <Setter Property="android:Button.UseDefaultPadding" Value="false" />
              <Setter Property="android:Button.UseDefaultShadow" Value="true" />
              <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Quicksand-Regular.otf#Quicksand" />

              <Setter Property="MinimumHeightRequest" Value="50" />
              <Setter Property="MinimumWidthRequest" Value="50" />
              <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="DarkTurquoise"/>
              <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
              <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="60" />

            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And im creating my buttons by code like this..

```
public RadButton CustomButtonCreator(FoodModel food, int row, int col)
        {
            var data = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties;

            RadButton custombutton = new RadButton
            {
                Text =food.Name,
                ClassId = food.ClassId.ToString(),
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                MinimumHeightRequest = 50,
                WidthRequest = 300,
                BackgroundColor = Color.DarkTurquoise,
                TextColor = Color.Black,
                BorderColor = Color.White,
                CornerRadius = 60
            };
            buttonlist.Add(custombutton);

            custombutton.Clicked += async (sender, args) => OnButtonClicked(sender, args);

            var stackLayout = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = { custombutton }
            };
            custombutton.Behaviors.Add(new LongPressBehavior()); //LONG PRESS BEHAVIORS
            var yo = custombutton.Behaviors[0] as LongPressBehavior; //LONG PRESS BEHAVIORS
            yo.LongPressed += OnButtonLongPressed; //LONG PRESS BEHAVIORS
            custombutton.Behaviors[0] = yo; //LONG PRESS BEHAVIORS
            Grid.SetRow(stackLayout, row);
            Grid.SetColumn(stackLayout, col);
            ButtonGrid.Children.Add(stackLayout);           

            return custombutton;
        }
```

As i said it works fine for the regular button.
Now for the RadButton , the weird thing is that while the shadow doesn't get loaded on init, if i change the colors of the buttons back and forth the shadows appear!

I also tried setting the shadow by code

```
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;
....
custombutton.On <Android>().SetUseDefaultPadding(true).SetUseDefaultShadow(true);
```

But the result is exactly the same, which suggests that the shadow value is set but not taken into account at first. Are the RadButton's properties overridding the default ones? And is there a way to overcome this problem without having to use regular buttons?

Comment: You could put the button in a Frame and set the shadow of it .

Comment: I know but i read that it is poor performance wise, and i have like 20-30 buttons on a single page. And since this setting exists i'd like to avoid workarounds.

Comment: You could use MaterialButton . Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57786160/android-setoutlineambientshadowcolor-no-such-method-error-on-api-28/57789046#57789046

Comment: I just tried that, but the same problem still remains. Must be something else going on.

Comment: Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/effects-shadoweffect/

Comment: Cool effect, but unfortunately it doesn't work for buttons.

Comment: You could use custom renderer and set the style in xml then set the background of the button in renderer .